# repeated sound and counter more than one time

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have programmed a mini game in android
 in my code the sound file and the counter should work one  time when the button is pressed but it repaets  the sound file and increase the counter more than one randomly I dont know why
this the part of code causes the problem

```
public static void colaction(ImageView co,final ImageView iv,final TextView tx)   

{
    final int d;
 d=ch.checkans(co,tx);  //check ans right or wrong
 new CountDownTimer(6000,1000)
{   int x =d;



@Override
public void onFinish() {
    iv.setVisibility(4);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//new CountDownTimer(2000,1000)

//{

    //@Override
    //public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int a=0;int b=0;
         int c=0;int n;
        //chtxcol();
        n=changetxt(tx);
        chtxcol();
        while(true)
        {    a =choosecolor(colors,r);
        while(true)
        { b =choosecolor(colors,g);
        if (b!=a)
        break;  
        }
        while(true)
             {c =choosecolor(colors,o);
             if (c!=a && c!=b)
                 break;
             }
        if (a==n||b==n||c==n)
            break;

        }
        //Toast.makeText(, ""+a+"//"+b+"//"+c,100);

    //}

    //@Override
    //public void onTick(long arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//  }}.start();
        setlock(true);
}

@Override
public void onTick(long arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setlock(false);
    iv.setVisibility(1);
    //iv.startAnimation(anima);
    if ( x ==0)
    {
        f++;
        wrong.start();  
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);}
    else
        {t++;
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.checmarka);
c.start();}
}}.start();



}
```

Comment: Try debugging it with android studio? You can go step by step through your program to find out why it's acting weird.

Comment: when I decrease the counter's time the sound  works one time what's the relation between them

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, sorry.